# How do you counter a mangudai and paladin combo?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I am fairly new to Aoe2 . I just started playing multi-player game mode with my friend and he always takes me out in imperial age with Elite mangudai and a Paladin combo. He also micro-manages these units so they constantly work together against my forces. I don't have a favorite civilization, so anything that gives me an upper hand against this combo will be useful.

Comment: Mangudai are exclusive to Mongols.  Mongols don't have access to Paladin.  Can you explain a bit more?  Are you playing with all tech?  Are you playing a team game?  Keep in mind that E Mangudai and Paladin are possibly one of the most expensive unit combos one could possibly dream up, and one of the best open-land army compositions possible, but requires 2 civs.  You'll need to provide more details before we can help you further.

Comment: Paladin is available for mongols in stable after upgrade. Yes Im playing all tech, 1vs1 multi player, random map and standard resources. Im aware that it takes a lot of resources. But my friend collects enough resources to create 20 mangudai and 10 Paladin to finish my army with micro management

Comment: Paladin is not available to Mongols without all-tech.  One idea is to turn all-tech off.  Another idea is to get an identical army.  There are very few ways to counter such an army - it is very mobile and cannot be easily killed by anything other than itself.  A 3rd idea is to fight earlier before late imperial.

Comment: Alternativley, pikemen are incredibly effective against mounted units and only cost wood/food (two very abundant resources). You can pump out tons and tons of them for basically nothing. Build a ton of barracks. Furthermore Hussars have incredible anti projectile defense. (Also very cheap) Use your Hussars to chase his mangudai out of range then use your pikemen/halbrediers to just dice up those paladins. Also, all tech is NOT the proper way to play AOEII...

Comment: Pikemen are not at all effective against properly managed mangudai though, which makes their combination with paladin all the more devastating.  You will lose all of your food and wood very quickly by throwing pikemen at mangudai.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Turn off all tech. Problem solved :P
2. Exactly what the guy above said about using spearmen+skirmishers, but add in a handful of onagers to do splash damage to the whole bunch of them (needs careful micro not to damage your own troops)
3. Play **Saracen** against him (if you know he'll do it)

Here's why Saracen:

Unique is a pimped up camel (Mameluke) - bonus vs cavalry and mounted units.
Also - they have access to siege onager, which is just amazing.

Both those units are quite expensive, so fill in the rest of your army with lots of Elite Skirmishers (or spears to help against cav), which are v cheap in comparison. Even a handful of Hussars (only food) to draw the fire - I think that was mentioned already.

Answer (score 5):

Simple, Pikeman and Skirmishers. Skirmishers will beat any type of archers as long as you have them fully upgraded. Pikeman easily takes out any kind of calvary. Control both unit at the same time. If he sends Paly's first, then put your pikemen at the front. It'll be most beneficial if you can blend both your pikemen and skirmishers together, that way your skirms will be able to protect your pikemen from his Mangudais. While your pikemen will protect your skirmishers from his paladins.

Answer (score 2):

Use Byzantine cataphracts for a couple o reasons:

1. Byzantines reach Imperial Age faster than anybody . That means that you can rush Castles and upgrade your elite unit (Cataphracts) way faster than paladins.
2. Cataphracts has overall better stats and AoE damage via upgrades.

Pick up a mob of upgraded cataphracts, rush their units and enjoy the ravage.

Answer (score 0):

If you can build a small army of around 25 to 40  hand canneers, they chew through paladins like butter, but I don't know how they would do against archers, I'd advice hussar or light cavalry and then back those with the guns.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to disagree with using Byzantine cataphracts against Paladins and Mangudai. Cataphracts have no bonuses that help them against these units, and a fully upgraded Elite Cataphract actually loses 1v1 to a Paladin, and a properly micro-managed Mangudai will beat a Cataphract 1v1 as well.
I completely agree with the top answer; play as Saracens. Saracen camels and mamelukes are perfect counters to Paladins and Mangudai, especially if you have Zealotry researched to give them +30 HP. In this scenario, if you create an army of camels and/or mamelukes the same size as the Mongol army of Paladins and Mangudai, you should win. I'm going to test it out in AoE II now...

**...battle commencing...**

Just tested it. Yes, I was right, the Saracen army cleared up the Mongol army very easily. Mamelukes are expensive though, so you may not have as many, however camels are cheaper than paladins and mangudai, so it should be fine.